# validating dynamic controls using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

how do i validate dynamic textboxes which are generated at runtime using jQuery?

Comment: What do you want to validate?

Comment: How you create these textboxs, client side or server?

Comment: the textboxes are created dynamically on server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%    
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Attributes.Add("data-validateme","true");
        Page.Controls.Add(tb);
%>
```

Which will add an HTML5 data attribute.

```
<input type="text" data-validateme="true" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("*[data-validateme]").change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can use something like this:

```
$(function() {
$('input').each(function() {
    $('#' + this.id).live('onchange', function() {  
        // VALIDATION Code
    });
});
```

Comment: live() does not support change yet :(